# How to avoid [] called on null in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there is a method in dart to judge whether an object is null or not, and then decide to get ['data'] or do nothing?

This is the error message:

> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Builder:
>   The method '[]' was called on null.
>   Receiver: null
>   Tried calling:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way to answer your question:

```dart
final data = list != null ? list[0] : null;
```

There is a shorthand method to do the same with properties and methods of any object : `a?.b` or `a?.b()`  would first null check `a` and then get `b` or call `b` respectively, if `a` is null return null.

**Such shorthand is not available for subscript only for properties and methods.**

Comment: Uh, [null-aware subscript operators aren't implemented](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/28389).

Comment: Corrected. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: `final data = list != null ? list[0] : null];` that so called 'simplest way' actually not simplest in comparison with `final data = list?.first;`

Comment: The question is not just about getting the first item. It could be any.

Answer (score 4):

Prefer `Null` aware index operator:

```
var item = yourList?[0] ?? defaultValue;
```